# 'height' of undefined with react-test-renderer library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-test-renderer

I have `Collapse` and `RadioGroup` components in my current component.
`in` prop of `Collapse` component bonded to state.
When I want to change the value of `RadioGroup` with `onChange` prop, I get an error.
Because `in` prop of `Collapse` component equal to true, And the `Collapse` component should appear.

> This error appears in test mode with `react-test-renderer`

Some lines of my component:

```
. . .
const [discountType, setDiscountType] = useState('total')
. . .
const handleChange = event => {
  setDiscountType(event.target.value)
}
. . .
  <RadioGroup value={discountType} onChange={handleChange}>
. . .
  <Collapse in={discountType === 'separate'}>
      . . .
  </Collapse>
. . .
```

Test file:

```
const component = create(<MyComponent />)
const instance = component.root

it('MyComponent snapshot', () => {
  const tree = component.toJSON()
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot()
})

it('MyComponent handleChange correctly', () => {
  const value = 'separate'
  act(() => {
    instance.findByType(RadioGroup).props.onChange({ target: { value } }) // This line produces Error
    component.update(<MyComponent />)
  }
})
```

As you can see, Error occurs after call `handleChange` function with `seperate` value.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined
```

```
at Object.handleEnter [as onEnter] (node_modules/@material-ui/core/Collapse/Collapse.js:106:23)
at Transition.performEnter (node_modules/react-transition-group/cjs/Transition.js:282:16)
at Transition.updateStatus (node_modules/react-transition-group/cjs/Transition.js:253:14)
at Transition.componentDidUpdate (node_modules/react-transition-group/cjs/Transition.js:215:10)
at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:12232:22)
at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15354:7)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11758:14)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11807:16)
at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11860:31)
at commitRootImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15092:9)
at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:697:12)
at runWithPriority (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2013:10)
at commitRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14932:3)
at finishSyncRender (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14439:3)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14417:9)
at node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2063:24
at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:697:12)
at runWithPriority (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2013:10)
at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2058:7)
at flushSyncCallbackQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2046:3)
at batchedUpdates (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14460:7)
at act (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:17271:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (MyComponent.test.js) // My test file
```

Comment: Material UI requires some extra setup to make it work. Some useful information can be found there: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17119